# Oracle EX and SQL Plus: How to recover dump file?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have .dmp and .log files.  I need to recover the database schema and data using SQLPlus or some feature of EX.  How do I do that?  I've tried the RECOVER command and impdp.  No luck, or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle? How was the .dmp file created? You can look at the first line in your .dmp file (assuming it's a file produced by exp) to get the version of the utility that dumped it. Likely, you will need to use imp, although I don't know what problems you were experiencing with impdp - error messages and the command line being used would be helpful. Assuming this was produced by exp, RECOVER will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use "imp Scott/Tiger@Machine file=MyDump.dmp" in EX?

P.S: I Assume Oracle Ex == Oracle Express

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt and type imp user/password@db
you will be prompt to provide the file and path.

if you get message like:
IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
this means that the file was created with data pump or that the source version is newer.
if not, follow the prompt it should be really straight forward.